# How to generalize a particular integral representation of Gamma function to negative parameter coefficients?

Tags: gamma-function

[DLMF 5.9.1](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9#i) reproduces the result from exercise 1.1 from ch 2.1 of Olver's Asymptotic and Special Functions:

$$\frac{1}{\mu}\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{\mu}\right)\frac{1}{z^{\nu/\mu}}=\int_{0}^%
{\infty}\exp\left(-zt^{\mu}\right)t^{\nu-1}\mathrm{d}t$$

That result is valid when $\Re\nu, \mu, \Re z>0$.

Is there a simple generalization when $\nu, \mu<0,\ z>0,\ \nu,\mu,z\in\mathbb{R}$? It seems to me that in that case, the formula becomes $-\frac{1}{\mu}\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{\mu}\right)\frac{1}{z^{\nu/\mu}}$, but is there a simple way to show it?

The motivation for this came from statistics, where one had to show that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)\ b^{a}}\ \exp\left(-\frac{1}{b}t^{-1}\right) t^{-a-1}\mathrm{d}y=1 \text{ (i.e. is a PDF)},$$ with $a,b>0$.

Applying DLMF 5.9.1 while ignoring the constraints yields -1 instead of +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp \left( { - zt^{ - \alpha } } \right)t^{ - \beta  - 1} dt} & \mathop  = \limits^{t = 1/s}  - \int_{ + \infty }^0 {\exp \left( { - zs^\alpha  } \right)s^{\beta  - 1} ds} \\ & \;\,= \int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp \left( { - zs^\alpha  } \right)s^{\beta  - 1} ds} = 
\frac{1}{\alpha }\Gamma \left( {\frac{\beta }{\alpha }} \right)\frac{1}{{z^{\beta /\alpha } }}
\end{align*}
when $\alpha$, $\beta>0$. Take $\alpha=-\mu$ and $\beta=-\nu$, with $\mu$, $\nu<0$ and you have your result.